# How to trigger an event to an element created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using daterangepicker like this :

```
$('#myInput').daterangepicker({
'param1': value1,
'param2': value2,
'param3': value3,
...
}, function(...) {
...
})
```

This works fine if my input is created with the DOM. But if my input is created dynamically after the DOM, this does not work, normally I should do something like this :

```
$('body').on('daterangepicker..........event', '#myInput', function() {

})
```

But I don't know how to do it, thanks for help

Comment: Just wait for the input to be in the DOM before calling `.daterangepicker`?

Comment: do `$('#myInput').daterangepicker({..` same thing after DOM load

Comment: myInput is created dynamically

Comment: Then add your code directly after your code that creates it dynamically...

Comment: Then you need to instantiate the datepicker right after you create the input

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is there another way to do it ? outside the function that creates the input dynamically

Comment: You could use a mutation observer, but that's massive overkill.

Comment: Depends on what creates / how you create the input.  If you call a function that makes an ajax call you could return the ajax promise and add a .done to it

Comment: @freedomn-m the input is created after a click

Comment: You could add your own event.  Listen to the event to add the daterangepicker and raise the event inside your click event.  Not much different from just adding a call to your function that adds the daterangepicker though tbh.

Comment: Is the ``daterangepicker`` created after some event fires(like click) or simply from data on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Simply becuz Your DOM has not been created.
So you can archive this by register element wrapper the #my-input

So that is the reason why you use "body" and works fine.

You can give it a try the following sample

```html
<div id="my-div"> <input id="my-input" /> </div>
```

```js
$("#my-div").on('daterangepicker..........event', '#myInput', function() {

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a container and inject it into.

```js
$(function() {
     let html = document.getElementById('container');
    setTimeout(() => {
     // Dynamically adding datepicker
      html.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>'; // 
      let dp = document.getElementById('datepicker'); 
      dp.classList.add('DatePicker');
      $('.DatePicker').datepicker();
    }, 500)
  });
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="container"></div>
  
</body>
</html>
```